# Which web browsers apply a default CSS margin/padding on the body element by default?

Tags: css, layout, html

What web browsers apply a default CSS magin and/or padding on the body element by default?

I know Google Chrome applies a 8px margin, and I've heard that other browsers have a default padding as well.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what all the different padding values are per browser, but most people get around this by using a `reset.css` such as this popular one: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @mwan - Most people? I'd say most people don't. And there are good reasons not to.

Comment: @Rob: There are pros and cons to it, like everything. For me the time saving pros outweigh the (mostly evangelical) cons. Also, I see it was good enough for your own website as it has a `reset.css` :P

Comment: I really don't understand why everybody has to harp on resets when all the OP is asking is what the browser defaults are.

Comment: @mwan - You might also have noticed I do virtually nothing with that site and it's almost untouched for three years. No, I have not used a reset anywhere else since but thanks for noticing and I'll remove that.

Answer (score 3):

Most browsers have default margin for `body` element. IE9 gives 15px vertical and 10px horisontal, Opera 11 gives 8px, yet this can and does change between versions, so you realy **should** incorporate css reset in your stylesheets, be it home-brew `padding:0;margin:0;`, [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/).

Comment: Thanks! What about padding? Do you know of any browsers that add a default padding to the body element?

Comment: Seems like none adds it. But you can never be sure ;)

Comment: Margins have been the tradition since the 90s (probably around the time or even before I was born). I highly doubt any browser would pull a smart one and add padding instead of margins. But still...

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple test page, like this one, and try all the browsers you're interested in. From what I've seen, browsers seem to have a non-zero default for `margin`, and 0 for `padding`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Default padding on body tag</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#top').text($('body').css('margin-top'));
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    margin-top: <span id="top"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```