# How to remove unwanted space in html top, top left and right?

Tags: html, css

I want to know why in HTML I got an unwanted space when I made a table of the whole page. How can I remove that space? I tried `cellpadding="0"` and `border="0"`

[Space between the address bar and the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrNIY.png)

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Lord Machine Admin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="Blue" border="1" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body element has a default margin.  Just set the body `margin` to `0` and your all set.

A "CSS RESET" is way overkill and should not be required.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Lord Machine Admin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="Blue" border="1" cellpadding="0">
      <tr height="100px">
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In most browsers, [the `<body>` element gets a default CSS margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439494/which-web-browsers-apply-a-default-css-margin-padding-on-the-body-element-by-def) (in Chrome, it’s 8 pixels).

You can remove this default style using CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Lord Machine Admin</title>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="Blue" border="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

As the other answers mention, there are various groups of CSS reset styles out there that attempt to reverse default browser styles in a sensible way, giving you a blank slate to work with.

However, that might be more CSS than you need in your case, or you might end up re-setting default browser styles that you actually want to keep.

Comment: @arctelix: that’s quite alright, we’re singing from the same hymn sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use a "CSS Reset" with the CSS Universal selector and remove any default white space that may be browser specific rendered white space or coming from another style sheet:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

A good place for the "CSS Reset" is at the top of your main website style sheet and your main style sheet should come after any external style sheets like bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS RESET . You can use it to reset all the default pre applied margins paddings etc.. 
 /* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
       v2.0 | 20110126
       License: none (public domain)
    */

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```