# My links are on top of each other

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

My links for some reason are on top of each other since I changed all metrics from pixels to %. Here is my code. I am pretty sure it is a simple fix, but I just can't find an answer. Here is the code:

```css
.left_column {
  line-height: 3%;
  float: left;
  padding: 5%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 70%;
  border: solid;
  position: relative;
  top: -11%;
  border: solid;
}
#nav_left_column li {
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial;
}
#nav_left_column a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3e3e3e;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#nav_left_column a:hover {
  background-color: #3e5869;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#nav_left_column a:visited {
  color: #357c49;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="left_column">
  <ul id="nav_left_column">
    <li><a href="What_s_new.html">What's New</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Digital_news.html">Digital News</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that's because of width: 10% for .left_column

Comment: the line-height is an issue here remove it or increase. I really don't know why you set it to 3%

Comment: Not, really. Increasing the width doesn't solve the problem. Links are still on top of each other.

Comment: Krzystof Duszczyk, increasing it is not setting links in the block either. What value would you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

This must be the culprit:

```
line-height: 3%;
```

Because it makes the line height of the links equal to 3% of the font size instead of 3% of the height. Simply get rid of it (or just don't set it to % because you don't need to use % everywhere) and it will be fine.

---

** UPDATE **

Since the line-height property was there to increase the space between the lines and it didn't work, you can use this:

```
#nav_left_column li {
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-top: 10px; /* take care of the links' claustrophobia~ */
}
```

Or, if you want the empty space between them to be taken by the links (in other words, the links to be "fat"):

```
#nav_left_column li {
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-top: 10px; /* take care of the links' claustrophobia~ */
}

#nav_left_column a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3e3e3e;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: My connection or stackoverflow died while I was posting it, so I accidentally posted it twice. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank, yeah that worked. However I really want to increase the space between lines. Could you suggest a way of doing it?

Comment: @MaxVisna Usually `line-height` is set in `px`, `pt`, or `em`. Pick a large enough number for one of those...

Comment: @Max Visna I've edited my answer now. This is what you wanted to do, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is setting the line-height to `3%`. I have no idea why you would do that, but that is stacking the links, increase the value, or just remove the rule (my recommendation), and your problem should fix.

See the alternate to line height in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11720229/6525260) (Or don't use percents.)

Answer (score -1):

The effect you are seeing is most likely a combination of the line-height and width properties. Which are effectively constraining the printable area of your container (the div) to 3% of the height of its parent container and 10% of the parents width.

```css
.left_column {
  --> line-height: 3%;
  float: left;
  padding: 5%;
  --> width: 10%;
  height: 70%;
  border: solid;
  position: relative;
  top: -11%;
  border: solid;
}
```

You can observe the effect by removing or altering those two properties.

Comment: Great Thank you. I fixed this. Now I am trying to move .left_column to the top by adjusting top value and it doesn't do anything. do you know what the issue might be looking at my code?

Comment: If you would like your column to be top left (pixel 0,0) of the browser window, you will have to account for the margin that most browsers add. See this article for a starting reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439494/which-web-browsers-apply-a-default-css-margin-padding-on-the-body-element-by-def